# Bibliographic entries: URL strings too long

Tags: bibliographies, urls, apa-style

I want to cite and format the bibliographic references according to APA style. So I tried:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{apacite}
    \begin{document}
    \title{blabla}
        \author{blabla}
        \date{\today}
        \maketitle
    \cite{delistraty_2014}

    \bibliographystyle{apacite}
    \bibliography{ref.bib}
    \end{document}
```

But the output of the reference list seems weird
[image: Spaces are totally wrong, and the hyperlink of the website has a strange font.]

So what can I do to solve it out?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You need to load the `url` package and/or the `hyperref` package in order to enable line breaks in long URL strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To typeset long URL strings, it's a good idea to load the `url` package and/or the `hyperref` package. That way, LaTeX is much more likely to "find" permissible line break opportunities.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@misc{delistraty_2014,
  author = "Cody C. Delistraty",
  title  = "The Beauty-Happiness Connection",
  year   = 2014,
  month  = "Aug.",
  howpublished = "Atlantic Media Co.", 
  url    = "https://www.theatlantic.com/health/archive/2014/08/the-beautyhappiness-connection/375678/",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces]{url}

\begin{document}
\cite{delistraty_2014}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want the URL string to use the main text font instead of a monospaced font, just issue the directive `\urlstyle{same}` after loading the `url` package.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks very much! Another problem is what if I want the url in the reference to be a hyperlink? What should I do, instead of "\cite{xxxxx}"?

Comment: @user155860 - If you want to enable hyperlinking of URL strings, you must load the `hyperref` package.

Comment: However, if I use "hyperref" package, I can't use \cite{xxx} command. So what should I do?

Comment: @user155860 - This is very strange. Please tell us how you load the `hyperref` package. In particular, do you load it *after* the `url` package? If not, you need to change that. Also, try loading the `apacite` package with the option `natbibapa`.

Comment: Yes,`hyperref` going _after_ `url` solves the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Loading the `xurl`-package should solve the problem:

```latex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@misc{delistraty_2014,
  author = "Cody C. Delistraty",
  title  = "The Beauty-Happiness Connection",
  year   = 2014,
  month  = "Aug.",
  howpublished = "Atlantic Media Co.", 
  url    = "https://www.theatlantic.com/health/archive/2014/08/the-beautyhappiness-connection/375678/",
}
\end{filecontents}
    
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{apacite}
    \usepackage{xurl}
    \begin{document}
    \title{blabla}
        \author{blabla}
        \date{\today}
        \maketitle
    \cite{delistraty_2014}

    \bibliographystyle{apacite}
    \bibliography{ref.bib}
    \end{document}
```

[image: The compilde document]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You could improve your answer if you try it out and share your MWE and your result which shows that your recommendation really solves the problem.

Comment: Thankx a bunch @Οὖτις, just did that